# How can I tell if my page is set as the user's homepage?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can detect when my page has been set as the user's homepage in their browser?

I'm most interested in something in javascript, but I'd be happy to hear about other approaches as well.

**Edit**: I'm not looking for anything sneaky.  I'm wondering if there is anything that is explicitly allowed through the browsers to find out this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla/Firefox has a [`window.home()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.home) method which loads the user's home page.  This method could be used (in an iframe, maybe) combined with server access logging, to see if the site's home page is instantly requested loaded by the current user.

However, other browsers don't seem to support this javascript method.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't likely to be a foolproof method, as that's an intrusion into the privacy of the user.

One thing that comes to mind is checking for a referrer.  If the user arrived at your page without following a link, they a) typed the url, b) followed a bookmark, or c) have your page set as their homepage.  But that's about the best I can do.

Comment: Or d) Have referrers turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  You can tell if they got to your page by following a link or not.  Check the referrer.  However, the browser going to your page as the home page will not appear any different than the user typing in your page or using a bookmark.